# Apache camel capturing failover attempts before another failover does round robin

Tags: apache-camel, failover

I am using apache camel failover component with following route configuration:

```
<route id="jettyRouter" errorHandlerRef="defaultErrorHandler">
    <from uri="jetty:http://{{Jetty.entryPoint.host}}?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
    <loadBalance>
        <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2" roundRobin="true" >
            <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
            <process ref="customExceptionProcessor" />
        </failover>
        <to uri="direct:endpointRoute1" />
        <to uri="direct:endpointRoute2" />  
    </loadBalance>
</route>
```

I want to raise an email when ever connect exception is raised. However process associated to send email in my example is called only after connection exception thrown after maximumFailoverAttempts are exhausted. I want to send email for every connect exception before failover does round robin and choose next uri.

Is this possible in camel 2.14 or 2.17.0 ?

Thanks,
Anjana.

Comment: Did you try putting `doTry` and `doCatch` around `<from ... ` and then in doCatch you can call your processor where you can send mail. And you can again re throw that exception in the processor, so that it can go through the failover block and do the need full. In this case you can remove the processor from failover block

Comment: I added try and catch block and from my customExceptionProcess re throw connection exception. however the customexceptionProcess only gets called when failoverattempts are exhausted and there all the uri give connect exception. below is the configuration with try and catch.

Comment: <doTry>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
        <log message="In Jetty entry at {{Jetty.entryPoint.host}}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="com.sintecmedia.loadbalance.endpoint" />
        <loadBalance>
    <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2" roundRobin="true" >
   </failover>
              <to uri="direct:endpointRoute1" />
    <to uri="direct:endpointRoute2" /> 
      </loadBalance>
      <doCatch>
         <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
         <process ref="customExceptionProcessor" />
            </doCatch>
         </doTry>

Comment: Why don't you just catch the exception and send it to your error handler route instead of involving loadbalancers?

Comment: My requirement is to handle load load balancer exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thats is not what I meant, something like this

```
<route id="jettyRouter" errorHandlerRef="defaultErrorHandler">
  <doTry>
    <from uri="jetty:http://{{Jetty.entryPoint.host}}?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
  <doCatch>
    <process ref="customExceptionProcessor" /> <!--send mail and rethrow exception from this bean -->
  <end>
  <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
  <loadBalance>
        <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2" roundRobin="true" >
            <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
        </failover>
        <to uri="direct:endpointRoute1" />
        <to uri="direct:endpointRoute2" />  
  </loadBalance>
</route>
```

I have not tried this. Just a suggestion. Posting it as answer, since it is difficult to put this code as comment.

Comment: this would not help since unable to put dotry after route element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the failover load balancer. You cannot do custom processing per thrown exception.

You can do that with the regular error handler, where there is an `onExceptionOccurred` you can configure to call a `Processor`. But that feature is added recently, so may not be in those old versions of Camel you are using.

Comment: Thanks Claus. My requirement is to catch every connect exception and raise and email before load failover component select another uri to route when it encounters connect exception on an uri. From i understand this feature is not available in current camel version as well.

Comment: Take a look yourself if `onExceptionOccurred` is available in the Camel version you use. An alternative is to use `onRedelivery` which is called before trying again, and not 100% at the moment when the exception was thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Any one had encountered similar requirement of catching connect exception before round robin of failover component selects another endpoint.